# Unable to Add Custom Labels with multiple email domains in validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

Hi I need some help in a validation rule that I am building  to restrict email to a specific domains only (ex below)-

```
IF( 
NOT(CONTAINS($Label.XYZ_Domains, LOWER(Email))), 
true, 
false)
```

The label currently contains value in this format -
`%@gmail.com%%@yahoo.com%%msn.com`

and have also tried the below formats in custom label -

```
@gmail.com\\@yahoo.com
@gmail.com-@yahoo.com
@gmail.com:@yahoo.com
```

but not able to get it working. Can somebody help me here to have it working somehow. We are avoiding writing this using trigger

Comment: Your validation is working fine for me . In custom Label I have used this value: %@gmail.com%%@yahoo.com%%msn.com. Please let me know if you are trying to restrict something else.

Comment: May I know if the issue is resolved or still persist?

Comment: Does it allow you to add email domains of type yahoo.com or gmail.com for you with the validation rule @PriyaRanjan ?

Comment: No. it is not allowing to add email with Yahoo.com or Gmail.com or msn.com as validation rule is applied for that particular criteria which you have mentioned in the post.